# Symbol lookup error when loading a program. Symbol is defined in static library and can be seen using nm

Tags: linux, runtime, loader, symbols

I see the below error when running a program:

```
/usr/bin/getinfo: symbol lookup error: /usr/pkl/libinfo.so: undefined symbol: GetList
```

This function '`GetList`' is defined in a static library `liblist.a` that has been linked to the executable `/usr/bin/getinfo` and compiled with gcc. I can see that the executable getinfo has the symbol defined in it when I run 'nm' command. Here's the nm command output:

```
root@pkl $ nm /usr/bin/getinfo | grep GetList
080a3d89 T GetList
```

I have also checked using readelf command and here's the output:

```
root@pkl $ readelf -a /usr/bin/getinfo | grep GetList
 1080: 080a3d89 1777 FUNC   GLOBAL DEFAULT   15 GetList
```

libinfo.so shared library calls the function GetList which is defined in liblist.a static library. Both `libinfo.so` and `liblist.a` are listed as dependencies to the executable `/usr/bin/getinfo`. `liblist.a` is **not** added as a dependency to `libinfo.so`
I have also done `objdump -S /usr/bin/getinfo | grep GetList` and could see the assembly code of this function. However, when running the program, it crashes with symbol lookup error. This is not a shared library issue and I am unable to resolve it. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you are dynamically loading a shared object `/usr/pkl/libinfo.so` probably by using `dlopen(3)` or similar function.  It would be interesting to know how did you compile `getinfo` (the exact linking command) and how do you load the shared library (if it is calling `dlopen(3)` or automatically at program launch)  No static library info is available after the linking process (as the linking of a static library consists only in extracting the `.o` files from it and normal link them to the executable), so saying that `GetList` comes from a static library or from a `*.o` object is of no interest here.

Show the exact command sequence to link the `getinfo` executable, and if you load `libinfo.so` through a call to `dlopen(3)` some context around the call should be of interest also.  Also, knowing if `GetList` is a C or C++ function should be nice to know, as C++ symbols are name mangled by the compiler to cope with parameter list type matching. Perhaps you see a C style function in the output to `nm` but you are trying to call a C++ `GetList` function.

By the way, what do you mean with dependency info about some static library, after linking has been done. I suppose the `GetList` function is included in the executable, as you show it in the `nm(1)` output. So it should be available to the `libinfo.so` shared object when dynamic linking (this depends on some options to the linker in the linking process --- this is the reason to ask for the exact linking command you used)  It is also important to know the exact linking command of the `libinfo.so` module, if possible.

Edit your question and add the missing info, so we can help you.